# Local ASP.NET Website doesn't run without Internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I created an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2008. 
The website runs when I am connected to the Internet, but when I don't have Internet, it doesn't start (it just keeps on loading neverendlessly). 
This is an anomaly of some type: the website is local on my PC so it should run without Internet. Any clues/suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does your site do?  Does it try to make an internet connection at some point?  Are you sure that the site it is trying to start is localhost (project - properties)?

Comment: Or this may be a routing issue of your PC, try pinging/tracing localhost and 127.0.0.1 and see if they jump anywhere, if they do your hosts and lmhosts files may have some bogus entries in them

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 could jump somewhere???

Comment: Hello, thank you both. Hyp, I pinged localhost and that worked. Paddy, I went to the Project properties, looked into the Web tab, should I change something there?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using firefox and behind a proxy, you need to add localhost to your 'no proxy' list. This is Tools -- Options -- Advanced -- Network -- Settings -- and add it to the list. I'm fairly certain there's something similar for IE.

Comment: And if you are using IE, you need to bypass proxy for local addresses. tools -- internet options -- connections -- lan settings and tick the box (IE8)

Comment: Horray, it worked! Thank you so much Chris and the others! I went to Connections - Local settings - I typed in "proxy" for address, 8080 port and ticked "Bypass proxy server for local addresses". Works like a charm! Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Of course, could you please tell me how to mark it as an answer? Thank you in advance, Chris.

Comment: i havent asked a question on here for a little while but is there a see through tick on the left of my answer under the up/down vote option? click that :) - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using some external resources: database, JavaScript files like jQuery, statistics script etc. Try to remove it and check if page loads.

Comment: No, I don't use any external resources. Thanks psur. It's probably something that I should change in the project properties, but don't know where to look.